# How can I change a response to an employer message?

Tags: support, jobs

I recently got a message from an employer, and wished to respond as Interested.  I think I selected 'Interested' (but I may mistakenly picked Not Interested), and I wrote a brief message expressing my interest.  I clicked send, and then I noticed that the message is marked 'Not Interested'.

Can I change my response?  Or send another message clarifying the mistake?  Or should I just hope that he/she reads the message, and reaches out again?

Also, would it be possible to see a screenshot of what the message would have looked like with the options to select my interest level?  I am curious how I managed to mess this up.  Perhaps the UI could be improved, to avoid user-errors?  (Or maybe not, maybe I have no excuse :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey Patrick,

We've unresponded your message, so you should be able to go back into your account and resend your reply.

We did recently make some changes to this UI and depending on when you responded you would have seen the old one or the new one... At the moment it's two radio buttons - one that says "I'm interested" and one that says "I'm not interested".

Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up finding the recruiter's contact info on LinkedIn anyway, but this helps.